# Cannot connect to mongodb Atlas cluster using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I built my cluster, created database user, and contained my IP address to the whitelist.
But whenever I run this command, I get the following error.

`mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.vkqlr.mongodb.net/test" --username <my-username>`

*DNSProtocolError: Invalid record 0 of SRV answer for "_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vkqlr.mongodb.net": Incorrect result size*

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried for all possible answers but nothing worked out for me.
But got resolved by the following steps,
Clearing DNS using

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then changed the google dns to obtain dns automatically option in Adaptor ipv4 settings of Control panel

Another main thing is, i was trying to connect through SRV text. But, it didn't worked out until i specified the fields individually.

Answer (score 0):

You have some kind of DNS issue on your system. Try [another DNS resolver](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-dns-server).